# How to pass connection string to a class library?

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection-string

I have a project structure like

```
MySolution
    -FrontEnd
         -webforms
         -console
         -Mvc
    -Repositories
         -Dapper   (Class library)
    -Tests
```

How do I reference the connection string in my repository class library? I tried adding App.Config in my class library project but it is not available in Add New Items. I am using Visual Studio 2013 express for web. Thanks, Damien.

Comment: This might help - http://forums.asp.net/t/1394239.aspx

Comment: It's strange, check for Application Configuration File in "Add new item..." menu again. If there is none, create it manually and then include in project.

Also, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894153/should-the-connectionstring-come-from-the-mvc-project-or-the-data-project) might be useful

Comment: @Aishvarya that does not help me as I cannot access ConfigurationManager inside my Class Library maybe because I have started from a Blank application project.

Comment: I got this answer for more or less the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894153/should-the-connectionstring-come-from-the-mvc-project-or-the-data-project

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The .Config that applies to libraries is the one of the executing assembly using those libraries, so you don't have to add an App.Config to your project, it will use the App or Web.Config of your startup project.

In order to get access to the `ConfigurationManager` you need to add a reference to `System.Configuration` in your library project.

Comment: Thanks, for some odd reason I could not reference using ConfigurationManager, however it worked using WebConfigurationManager.

Answer (score 3):

Use web.config in the FrontEnd project. Do not use app.config in the Repositories project.

This article explains how to read the value from web.config.

http://www.connectionstrings.com/store-connection-string-in-webconfig/